# how to robustly parse a document for any headings and build a <ul> tree of just those headings

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, coffeescript

So I parse through a document in order to grab all the headings with stackHeadings(). I do this in order to build a Microsoft Word style document map with buildNav(). This currently works OK but its not very robust and breaks anytime the headings do not follow a strict order... e.g. (If you start with an H2 it breaks, if you nest a H3 under and H1 it breaks, etc...)

I can't quite figure out the best way to fix this (make it more robust). I'm taking advantage of jQuery's `nextUntil' function to find all the h2s between two h1s.

One possibility is replacing:

```
elem.nextUntil( 'h' + cur, 'h' + next )
```

with

```
elem.nextUntil( 'h' + cur, 'h' + next + ',h' + (next + 1) + ',h' + (next + 2) ... )
```

to find ALL subheadings between two headings of the same level. But now h3 children of h1s would only be nested one level rather than two.

So then you'd have to compare the current heading level with the parent heading level, and if there's a jump of more than one (h1 -> h3), you'd have to create an empty child between them as a nesting placeholder for the missing h2.

Any ideas or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

```
stackHeadings = (items, cur, counter) ->

    cur = 1 if cur == undefined
    counter ?= 1
    next = cur + 1
    for elem, index in items
      elem = $(elem)
      children  =  filterHeadlines( elem.nextUntil( 'h' + cur, 'h' + next ) )
      d.children = stackHeadings( children, next, counter ) if children.length > 0
      d


filterHeadlines = ( $hs ) ->
    _.filter( $hs, ( h ) -> $(h).text().match(/[^\s]/) )

buildNav = ( ul, items ) ->
    for child, index in items
        li = $( "<li>" )
        $( ul ).append( li )
        $a = $("<a/>")
        $a.attr( "id", "nav-title-" + child.id )

        li.append( $a )

        if child.children
            subUl = document.createElement( 'ul' )
            li.append( subUl )
            buildNav( subUl, child.children )

items = stackHeadings( filterHeadlines( source.find( 'h1' ) ) )
ul = $('<ul>')
buildNav( ul, items)
```

Comment: It might help if you attach an example of some of the HTML you're trying to parse.

Comment: It seems like you need to clarify what you want out of this. Do you want to enforce correctness so that only h1 and h2 can follow an h1, and only h1, h2, or h3 can follow h2; do you want to enforce that an hX tag can't be inside another hX tag? Or do you want to just do your best to honor the seeming intent of whatever document you receive?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I threw together some JavaScript that will do what you want http://jsfiddle.net/fA4EW/

It's a fairly straightforward recursive function that consumes an array of elements (nodes) and builds the UL structure accordingly. To be consistent with the question I add the placeholder (empty) list elements when you from an H1 to an H3 etc.

```
function buildRec(nodes, elm, lv) {
    var node;
    // filter
    do {
        node = nodes.shift();
    } while(node && !(/^h[123456]$/i.test(node.tagName)));
    // process the next node
    if(node) {
        var ul, li, cnt;
        var curLv = parseInt(node.tagName.substring(1));
        if(curLv == lv) { // same level append an il
            cnt = 0;
        } else if(curLv < lv) { // walk up then append il
            cnt = 0;
            do {
                elm = elm.parentNode.parentNode;
                cnt--;
            } while(cnt > (curLv - lv));
        } else if(curLv > lv) { // create children then append il
            cnt = 0;
            do {
                li = elm.lastChild;
                if(li == null)
                    li = elm.appendChild(document.createElement("li"));
                elm = li.appendChild(document.createElement("ul"));
                cnt++;
            } while(cnt < (curLv - lv));
        }
        li = elm.appendChild(document.createElement("li"));
        // replace the next line with archor tags or whatever you want
        li.innerHTML = node.innerHTML;
        // recursive call
        buildRec(nodes, elm, lv + cnt);
    }
}
// example usage
var all = document.getElementById("content").getElementsByTagName("*");
var nodes = []; 
for(var i = all.length; i--; nodes.unshift(all[i]));
var result = document.createElement("ul");
buildRec(nodes, result, 1);
document.getElementById("outp").appendChild(result);
```

Comment: I've been working on implementing your code, which looks pretty good. One thing I ran into is that the nodes can have properties, which seems to put in extra "" that this algorithm can't handle.

Comment: So in trying to understand your example I went and tried to convert it into a more jQuery based solution that can handle "'s... There is something I don't get about the magic of how you swap elm and li, and the appended elements you gather along the way. I put your example in another fiddle to demonstrate the conversion. Mind giving it a look and see if you can understand where mine is screwing up? http://jsfiddle.net/funkyeah/s8m2t/3/

Comment: I also posted the follow-on question I aksed above, over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17451231/jquery-vs-plain-javascript-differences-between-append-and-appendchild-when-bui

Comment: @funkyeah - http://jsfiddle.net/s8m2t/8/ your bug was the difference between jQuery.append and DOM.appendChild. jQuery does not return the child with $.append(child) it returns the same list so you can use chaining. The DOM.appendChild(child) returns the child.

Comment: Yes, thank you... jquery's appendTo helped me solve it... I made the jQuery variant in the other answer based on your answer

Answer (score 3):

You could simply use the [jQuery TOC plugin](http://projects.jga.me/toc/), it appears they're [doing it](https://github.com/jgallen23/toc/blob/master/lib/toc.js) like this:

```
$('h1,h2,h3').each(function(i, heading) {
    ...
}
```

Of course, this simply treats all `h1`, `h2` and `h3` equally and creates the TOC by considering the nesting and the document order of the elements only. But isn't that the desired behaviour?

It would look strange to have a `h3`, which is directly inside a `h1`, double indented in the TOC. If you cannot live with that inconsistency, instead of inserting the missing `h2` in between, I would consider cleaning up the HTML and converting the `h3` into a `h2`.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery+Coffescript solution based on @LastCoder 's answer
http://jsfiddle.net/Sydky/1/

```
buildRec = (headingNodes, $elm, lv) ->
  # each time through recursive function pull a piece of the jQuery object off
  node = headingNodes.splice(0,1)
  if node && node.length > 0
    curLv = parseInt(node[0].tagName.substring(1))
    if curLv is lv # same level append an il
        cnt = 0
    else if curLv < lv # walk up then append il
        cnt = 0
        loop
            $elm = $elm.parent().parent()
            cnt--
            break unless cnt > (curLv - lv)
    else if curLv > lv # create children then append li
        cnt = 0
        loop
            li = $elm.children().last() # if there are already li's at this level
            if ($elm.children().last().length == 0)
                li = $("<li>").appendTo($elm);
            $elm = $("<ul>").appendTo(li);
            cnt++
            break unless cnt < (curLv - lv)
    li = $("<li>").appendTo($elm);
    li.text(node[0].innerText);
    # recursive call
    buildRec headingNodes, $elm, lv + cnt
```

usage

```
headingNodes = $('#entry').children().filter(":header")
result = $('<ul>')
buildRec(headingNodes,result,1)
result.html()
```