# jQuery vs. plain javascript: differences between append and appendChild when building DOM tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, recursion

I asked question about parsing a document for headings and creating a nested dom structure (via and unordered list )

[how to robustly parse a document for any headings and build a <ul> tree of just those headings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17347029/how-to-robustly-parse-a-document-for-any-headings-and-build-a-ul-tree-of-just)

In the second answer a solution was proposed along with a fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/fA4EW/

The solution is close but doesn't seem to work for elements containing properties with quotes, so I tried to refactor it in jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/funkyeah/s8m2t/3/

I feel like I am really close to making it work but the resolving the different between how

elm/li.appendChild and my codes $elm/li.append (they seem to return different values and modify the elm/$elm object differently)

```
      do {
            li = elm.lastChild;
            if(li == null)
                li = elm.appendChild(document.createElement("li"));
            elm = li.appendChild(document.createElement("ul"));
            cnt++;
        } while(cnt < (curLv - lv));
    }
    li = elm.appendChild(document.createElement("li"));
    // replace the next line with archor tags or whatever you want
    li.innerHTML = node.innerHTML;
```

Comment: Could you please show an example for the code that doesn't cope with quoted properties?

Comment: I tried doing a similar fiddle but it seems to work. My assessment of why the second answer to the original question "did not work" may be incorrect (It may be user error only). I'll have to go try and reproduce now. I still think the question about why the two methods behave differently in this instance is still valid. Of lesser importance, I also believe there is value in finding a jQuery based solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> differences between append and appendChild

Well, the [jQuery variant](http://api.jquery.com/append/) is more robust. It also takes multiple arguments, of type htmlString, jQuery collection or Arrays of elements, or even a callback function. And it automatically clones the elements if they are to be inserted into multiple parents. The [native method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) only takes single nodes (or single DocumentFragments).

> they seem to return different values

Yes. `.append()` returns the context jQuery collection (to which it appends), while `.appendChild` returns the appended element.

This seems to be the problem in your code, a naive transformation would lead to a different `li` value. If you do need to get the child back (there are simpler solutions), you might have a look at the [`.appendTo` method](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).

> and modify the elm/$elm object differently

No, they don't. Both put the appended elements to the end of the parent's children collection. You might have problems with setting the `innerHTML` value of the return value which is not what you expected (see above).

Comment: so the issue in doing this with jQuery seems like it will be that my $elm will only ever be the node I am creating and not a pointer to a sub-node that I am currently building (like in the first solution)... so $elm.parent().parent() won't work right because I am not correctly building the whole structure

Comment: how does the overall elm object not get destroyed and replaced with a ul every time elm = li.appendChild(document.createElement("ul")); is called

Comment: appendTo is the solution... at least for my approach... I sitll don't understand the above question, but http://jsfiddle.net/Sydky/1/ demonstrates appendTo works